# Trying to see if wall I removed 1.5 years ago was load bearing

Tags: structural, load-bearing

We bought a house awhile back and removed a wall we think was there to divide the kitchen from the dining room. We wanted a more open concept. Just want some assurance the wall was not load bearing. We have vaulted ceilings and the wall was not connected to the peak of the ceiling.

Comment: A load bearing wall should be supported underneath by a beam/wall on a cement floor/footings.  Close to the centre of the house is another sign.  Not having the roof falling down yet, is a also a possible sign it is/was not load bearing.  Having an engineer/building contractor check the wall before removing it and hoping the roof does not fall down is money well spent.

Comment: A few images of the current configuration and a layout sketch of where the removed wall was could be helpful.

Comment: You've asked the [same question twice](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/286371/trying-to-see-if-wall-i-removed-1-5-years-ago-was-load-bearing). Please delete one of these and consolidate all the info and pictures into the other.

Answer (score 0):

Ruling a wall as load bearing can be somewhat easy. Just find a familiar pattern for load bearing walls and you're done. Ruling a wall as non-load bearing, unfortunately, requires the complete exclusion of all load bearing wall patterns, and even then there's a possibility of something "clever" (turns out it wasn't so clever after the place collapses).

The roof hasn't collapsed yet. That's pretty good empirical evidence, but if the roof hasn't seen a substantial snow load between your "awhile back" and now, then now would be a good time to bring in an expert.