# Is this wall load bearing? Was removed 1.5 years ago

Tags: structural, load-bearing

[image: this was fully original wall before anything was done to it]Trying to see if this wall is load bearing. On the left, the wall went all the way up to the ceiling but the beam was not connected to any joist/beams in the attic. Also have vaulted ceilings but it was not attached to “peak” of ceiling. We removed to where the pencil is on the right. 1.5 years ago wall was taken down. [image: wall before removal]

Comment: 99.8% percent sure that wasn't load bearing. For a vaulted ceiling with that little stub of wall, a load bearing wall would run parallel to the ridge and directly below it. Either that or it would run perpendicular to the ridge and incorporate a column so that the ridge beam could be sized smaller.

Comment: You took the wall down 18 months ago and you're asking about it now?

Comment: Yes. When we removed it, we had 2-3 people say it is likely not load bearing but am just asking for assurance. So we did not do it blindly.

Comment: No offence but if you want assurance ask a qualified individual aka structural engineer. No matter how many people you ask if they aren't qualified it counts as 0.

Comment: why are you asking again? ... https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/286371/trying-to-see-if-wall-i-removed-1-5-years-ago-was-load-bearing